Unexpected Increase in Latency with More Readers in Multi-threaded Circular Queue Implementation in C++
I have implemented a circular queue using an array in C++. The queue uses two atomic variables, front and rear, to manage enqueue and dequeue operations. When an element is enqueued, rear is incremented, and when an element is dequeued, front is incremented.
I have created 16 instances of this circular queue, each with a size of 2^23 elements.
There are two scenarios I'm testing:
Scenario 1:
There are 2 reader threads.
Each reader thread is pinned to a separate CPU core and isolated.
Each reader is responsible for 8 of the 16 queues and sequentially checks each queue for packets, performing dequeue operations when packets are found, followed by certain processing.
Another thread enqueues elements into different circular queues.
Scenario 2:
There are 8 reader threads.
Each reader thread is pinned to a separate CPU core and isolated.
Each reader is responsible for 2 of the 16 queues and sequentially checks each queue for packets, performing dequeue operations when packets are found, followed by certain processing.
Another thread enqueues elements into different circular queues.
Metric:
The primary metric for comparison in both scenarios is the time taken by an element between enqueue and dequeue (latency or time spent by a packet inside the queue).
Problem:
Naturally, I expected that increasing the number of reader threads would decrease the latency. However, I observed the opposite: the latency increased when more readers were employed.
Additionally, I noticed that when more reader threads are employed, some of the threads have lower CPU utilization (around 70-80%) despite having an infinite while loop present in them.
Question:
Why might the latency increase when more readers are added? Are there specific concurrency or cache-related issues in my implementation that could explain this behavior?
What could be causing the lower CPU utilization in some threads when more reader threads are used?
Additional Information:
The code is written in C++.
Core pinning and isolation have been done for all threads to avoid interference.
I have tried checking for any contention issues or any other but could,nt find any.

As you'll see all too common here, you'll need to provide more details (e.g. a code sample) in order to obtain an answer.  From what you've written so far I would be looking at how the data is structured; is it cache-line aligned?  Will multiple threads be accessing the same cache lines?  See other threads on "False Sharing" for more detail.

When you say circular queue based on a fixed size (2^23) array, you mean you have taken care of wrapping the queue around the end and the queue is always large enough to hold all your data? How large are the elements in the queue? Just so that one can estimate the memory requirement. Everything you said makes sense and I would also search for errors in the implementation first. Show us some code please?

@Marcell, The size of a single element is 42 bytes and there are 18 such queues, so the total memory requirement would be around 18422^23 bytes ~ 5.9 GB and our RAM is of 64 GB. Also Queue is large enough to handle all the data, in case it gets full ,the writer thread waits to enqueue an element

Now there is one example where one can mess it up. The writer locks the queue, but the queue is full and so the writer waits to enqueue the next element. The reader waits for the lock and nothing ever happens.

@Marcell, the mechanism doesn't use a single lock where writer/reader takes the lock and free it, rather both writer and reader can enqueue and dequeue from the queue. also empty and full conditions have been implemented correctly to check on reader and writer side respectively.

@Den-Jason,Due to some restrictions, I cannot share the code. The size of each element is 42 bytes, so it is likely not cache-aligned. What potential latency issues might arise in the scenarios described in the post?

Are the atomic variables for different queues allocated in different cache lines or is there potential for cache-line bouncing?

Another possibility is that you do test-and-set instead of test and test-and-set logic, hammering the queues with RMW instructions and that delays other threads accessing that cache line. Of course this would be much easier to examine if you did a proper minimal, reproducible example like you are supposed to on this website.

@Homer512, Thanks for the reply. All the atomic variables are in different cache lines, and there is no potential of cache bouncing as one thread is incrementing a 'rear' variable and another thread is reading it.  and the same goes for 'front' variable. As far as sharing the code , i might get fired if i post the code here.

You're not supposed to post your company code. You are supposed to come up with a generic example that replicates the same behavior, preferably something you wrote in your free time. Then we are not working on your company's code, we help understand a fellow computer scientist a generic algorithmic problem.
